# Karliah not moving to Ragged Flagon

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I couldn't find Karliah in the Ragged Flagon so I went to Snow Veil Sanctum and she was stuck trying to open a door. When I opened it she didn't do anything and she's not coming to the Ragged Flagon. I went back after a few days (in game) and she is just standing there.

Why is this happening, and what should I do to make her move to Ragged Flagon?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times when a npc is stuck you can bump into him/her by sprinting, this makes the npc move and reposition. While repositioning the npc will pickup whatever it was trying to do, like entering a door.

It helped me quite some times when dialogs interfered with npc movements and left them 'hanging'.